# ORDER BY MAX(`field_name`) Using GROUP BY

Tags: php, mysql

I'm currently working on a soccer website and a feature I'm developing goes back through history to see which player(s) scored the most goals each year.

I have a working solution, but think there would be a simpler and efficient way of going about it.

Here is some example data:

```
-----------------------
year | name    | goals
-----------------------
  1  | player1 |  6
  1  | player2 |  8
  1  | player3 |  4
  2  | player1 |  3
  2  | player2 |  5
  2  | player3 |  2
  3  | player1 |  7
  3  | player2 |  7
  3  | player3 |  3
```

Using the following query, I am able to retrieve a portion of the data I require.

> SELECT `year`, MAX(`goals`) AS `goals` FROM `table` GROUP BY `year

```
------------
year | goals
------------
  1  |  8
  2  |  5
  3  |  7
```

Retrieving the correct value from the `name` column is proving more difficult though, as I am having to use `GROUP_CONCAT` in case of instances such as year 3, where more than one `name` is equal to the max value of `goals`.

At present, I am using two queries to get my desired outcome. I'm still using the query from above, but then using a PHP while loop to search through each year individually.

Here is my code:

```
$load_goals = $db->query("SELECT `year`, MAX(`goals`) AS `goals` FROM `table` GROUP BY `year` DESC);

while($goals = $load_goals->fetchObject())
{
    $players = $db->prepare("SELECT `year`, GROUP_CONCAT(`name` ORDER BY `name`) AS `name`, `goals` FROM `table` WHERE `year` = :year AND `goals` = :goals");
}
```

I've tried to combine the two queries into one but to no avail, so any guidance here would be much appreciated.

For clarification, this should be my final outcome. Note what happens in year 3, where `GROUP_CONCAT` has been served.

```
------------------------------
year | name            | goals
------------------------------
  1  | player2         |  8
  2  | player2         |  5
  3  | player1,player2 |  7
```

Comment: Do you see the missing double quote?? The syntax colouring should give you the hint!

Comment: Any apparent syntax errors on here are purely down to me being new to the site and adapting to the code and quote systems.

I have been provided with answers below which now solve my problem. Thank you for the response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want all the players who have the maximum number of goals.  One method uses variables.  Another requires a subquery.  The following uses a correlated subquery, but there are several ways to write this:

```
SELECT year, goals, GROUP_CONCAT(name ORDER BY name) as names
FROM table t
WHERE t.goals = (SELECT MAX(t2.goals) AS goals
                 FROM table t2
                 WHERE t2.year = t.year
                )
GROUP BY year, goals;
```

Comment: Works superbly. I'd looked into `join` and `union` but had no success with either.

Answer (score 0):

Just join your initial query back to the original table:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM yourTable t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT year, MAX(goals) AS goals
    FROM yourTable
    GROUP BY year
) t2
    ON t1.year  = t2.year AND
       t1.goals = t2.goals
```

Using this approach, there would be multiple records for years having more than one player tied for the greatest number of goals.  For example, if you ran this query against your sample data set, then players 1 and 2 would both appear for year 3, each player having 7 goals.

Comment: This does exactly as you describe and would likely be of use to other people with a similar problem.

For me, however, it was vitally important to make use of `GROUP_CONCAT` so any ties are delivered as one result, as provided by Gordon Linoff's solution above.

Thank you for providing an alternative.